# Конфиденциальные данные с защитой

Tags: база-данных, excel, access, веб-служба

Есть файл Excel, в котором хранится очень важная база данных. 
 
И есть сотрудник, который будет пополнять эту базу, но у этого сотрудника не должно быть прав на копирование, скачивание файла или редактирование уже заполненных данных.
И все это должно происходить в онлайне, но в таблице Excel. 
Чтобы собственник базы, мог в любой момент отредактировать данные сам в любой точке мира.
И при лишних движениях сотрудника в файле, отсылать уведомления смс на номер собственника или на email.
Если какие-либо готовые решения для этого?
На ум приходит только Google Docs, но там нельзя запретить пользователю с приоритетом редактирование, не копировать данные.

Спасибо за любую информацию!

Comment: если есть доступ на чтение, значит есть доступ на копирование. Например, с видео - вы хоть что делайте, видео всегда можно записать прямо с экрана любыми программками, нет под рукой программок - можно записать на камеру телефона. Текст - не видео, украсть его намного легче. Поэтому если боитесь за данные - не давайте их никому, пусть собственник сам все делает. Можно, конечно, пустить пыль в глаза заказчику, но если он все узнает - отвечать будете вы. Как вариант - придумать технологию, которая считывает сигналы головного мозга и передает туда информацию напрямую )) но тоже ненадежно

Comment: Вы можете сделать какую то форму для заполнения данных, и не показывать их сотруднику ( либо показывать только заполненные за последнюю сессию)

Comment: Выдать сотруднику пустой шаблон в экселе для заполнения данных, заполненные файлы периодически отсылаются собственнику для загрузки в базу, ну или в основной экселевский файл, а сотрудник начинает опять с пустого листа